# When I dynamically generated several rows in the column of Glance, why does clicking on one row trigger the click event for all rows?

Tags: android, glance

the code  dynamically generated several rows in the column of Glance,:

```kotlin
import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.glance.GlanceId
import androidx.glance.GlanceModifier
import androidx.glance.action.clickable
import androidx.glance.appwidget.GlanceAppWidget
import androidx.glance.appwidget.GlanceAppWidgetReceiver
import androidx.glance.appwidget.cornerRadius
import androidx.glance.appwidget.provideContent
import androidx.glance.background
import androidx.glance.layout.Alignment
import androidx.glance.layout.Box
import androidx.glance.layout.Column
import androidx.glance.layout.Row
import androidx.glance.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.glance.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.glance.layout.height
import androidx.glance.layout.padding
import androidx.glance.text.Text

class MediumWidgetReceiver : GlanceAppWidgetReceiver() {
    override val glanceAppWidget: GlanceAppWidget = MediumWidget()
}

class MediumWidget : GlanceAppWidget() {
    override suspend fun provideGlance(context: Context, id: GlanceId) {

        provideContent {
            Box(
                modifier = GlanceModifier.background(Color.White).padding(10.dp)
            ) {
                Column(
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top,
                    modifier = GlanceModifier
                        .background(Color.Gray)
                        .cornerRadius(10.dp)
                        .padding(vertical = 5.dp, horizontal = 2.5.dp)
                        .fillMaxSize()
                ) {
                    for (i in 0..2) {
                        Row(
                            modifier = GlanceModifier
                                .fillMaxWidth().padding(vertical = 10.dp)
                        ) {
                            Box(modifier = GlanceModifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .height(60.dp)
                                .background(Color.White)
                                .clickable {
                                    Log.d("MediumWidget", "click $i")
                                }) {
                                Text("click $i")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

the  glance version used:

```
    // For Glance support
    implementation "androidx.glance:glance:1.0.0-beta01"
    // For AppWidgets support
    implementation "androidx.glance:glance-appwidget:1.0.0-beta01"
```

ui:

[image]

when I click one of them, all row click events tiggered:
[image]

This situation only occurs when generating rows dynamically. I tried declaring it statically and the function worked normally.

code

```
                Column(
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top,
                    modifier = GlanceModifier
                        .background(Color.Gray)
                        .cornerRadius(10.dp)
                        .padding(vertical = 5.dp, horizontal = 2.5.dp)
                        .fillMaxSize()
                ) {
                        Row(
                            modifier = GlanceModifier
                                .fillMaxWidth().padding(vertical = 10.dp)
                        ) {
                            Box(modifier = GlanceModifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .height(60.dp)
                                .background(Color.White)
                                .clickable {
                                    Log.d("MediumWidget", "click 1")
                                }) {
                                Text("click 1")
                            }
                        }
                    Row(
                        modifier = GlanceModifier
                            .fillMaxWidth().padding(vertical = 10.dp)
                    ) {
                        Box(modifier = GlanceModifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .height(60.dp)
                            .background(Color.White)
                            .clickable {
                                Log.d("MediumWidget", "click 2")
                            }) {
                            Text("click 2")
                        }
                    }

                }
```

just tigger one row click event
[image]

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/285605910